# My divs won't stack directly under one another

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS problem here, my top div is just like I want it, but my link div fails here, if I put a padding in, it will be right under it, but will be higher than I want the div to be, so my issue here is:

I want the "link" div to be RIGHT under my "top" div. Right now it will add a little space between divs, and that space is white, so it looks bad.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeFile="Hovedside.master.cs" Inherits="Hovedside" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styling/stylinghoved.css" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 94%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<div id="siden">
    <div id="top">
        <table id="toptable">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" id="toptablemilto" class="auto-style1">
                Milto
            </td>
            <td style="margin:auto">
                login // kurv
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    søg:&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </div>
        <div id="links">
            <ul id="lin">
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">LK Produkter</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Flash   Light</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server">Philips</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="indhold">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="hovedsideplaceholder" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    <div id="bund">bund</div>
</div>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

#siden {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#top {
    height: 150px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #c2bcb5, #ffffff);
}

#top {}

#toptable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
#toptablemilto {
    width:80%;
    font-size:80px;
    padding-left:50px;
    line-height:0px;
}

#bund {
    clear:both;
}

#indhold {}

#links {
    height: 45px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c2bcb5, #ffffff);
}
#lin {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#lin ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
}
#lin li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#lin a:link, #nav a:visited, #nav:active {
    display: block;
    color: #574c3f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#lin a:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

changes css of #lin to display:inline-block & remove unwanted css

```
#lin {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7h0spbo/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why at the moment, but you can fix this by changing the `display` property for your `<ul>`.

```
#lin {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @teddylarsen No problem. If it worked for you, don't forget to check the "accept" checkmark to let others with the same problem know!

Answer (score 0):

I put a attribute margin on '#lin'. But i don't know if it is what you want

```css
#siden {
margin: auto;
width: 80%;
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#top {

height: 150px;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #c2bcb5, #ffffff);
}
#top {

}

#toptable {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}
#toptablemilto {
width:80%;
font-size:80px;
padding-left:50px;
line-height:0px;

}

#bund {
clear:both;

}

#indhold {

}

#links {

height: 45px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c2bcb5, #ffffff);

}
#lin {
display: block;
list-style: none;
text-align: center; 
}
#lin ul {
display: none;
list-style: none;

}
#lin li {
float: left;
display: block;
margin-top: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#lin a:link, #nav a:visited, #nav:active {
    display: block;
    color: #574c3f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#lin a:hover {
background-color: white;
}


#lin {
  
margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styling/stylinghoved.css" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        width: 94%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<div id="siden">
    <div id="top">
        <table id="toptable">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" id="toptablemilto" class="auto-style1">
                Milto
            </td>
            <td style="margin:auto">
                login // kurv
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    søg:&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>


    </div>
        <div id="links">
            <ul id="lin">
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">LK Produkter</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Flash   Light</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server">Philips</asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="indhold">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="hovedsideplaceholder" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    <div id="bund">bund</div>
</div>
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```